# Добавление элемента инфоблока к элементу инфоблока.

Tags: битрикс, php, элементы-управления

Добрый день.
Такой вопрос: 
Есть стандартный каталог битрикса. 
на странице детального просмотра товара нужно разместить форму(заполнения элемента иб) с кучей полей(отдельно от детально страницы каталога), и при сохранении этой формы нужно что бы в админке(при просмотре элемента) отображалось поле что эта форма добавлена к этому элементу(элемент каталога).

Как такое реализовать просто ума не приложу, перехватывать id? делать связку по свойствам иб. Если кто сталкивался подскажите,объясните.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать модуль веб-форм, если он есть в вашей редакции. Для привязки веб-формы к элементу каталога можете использовать модуль [Универсальные свойства привязки](http://g-rain-design.ru/components/links/) (выберите в параметрах свойства источник данных "Веб-формы" и пропишите шаблон пути к веб-форме в админке, и тогда в форме редактирования элемента каталога будет отображаться ссылка на привязанную форму). Для собственно вывода формы используйте соответвующий компонент модуля веб-форм (разместите его в файле element.php шаблона комплексного компонента каталога).

Comment: веб формы есть в редакции.
я так понимаю ваш модуль надо купить?
будет ли это работать со стороны пользователя?

Comment: Да, модуль платный (но недорогой). А что именно со стороны пользователя конкретно у вас должно работать? Ведь привязка веб-формы к товару ведь будет производится редактором? Хотя сам модуль работает в публичной части, например, со свойствами пользователя.

Comment: по факту надо что бы пользователь ничего не видел(поля привязки).
А администратор уже заходя в форму(элемент) которую завел пользователь, видел что этот элемент относится к тому элементу(типа как к разделу).

Comment: Я вам пока предлагал привязывать веб-формы, а не результаты заполнения веб-форм, их пользователь не будет и не должен видеть. Т.е. я полагал, что для разных товаров у вас может быть разный набор полей. Если вы хотите в каждом результате заполнения знать к какому элементу (товару) этот результат относится, то заведите в этой веб-форме скрытое поле, и записывайте туда ID товара, или ссылку, например (что удобнее). Если у вас список полей одинаковый для всех товаров, то никакой модуль, и никакие привязки не нужны.